# How to write javascript by using STRICT & Proper Event Binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need Some help here please.

Question:-
1)PROPER EVENT BINDING: Consider using the preferred .on() method rather than .click(), .bind(), .hover(), etc. For best performance and concise code use event delegation whenever possible

2)STRICT EQUALITY COMPARISON: For better performance please use Strict Equality Comparison.

I have no idea what to do actually and would appreciate some help.

This is my code (it’s quite long sorry):

Search Js:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
            var submitIcon = $('.searchbox-icon');
            var inputBox = $('.searchbox-input');
            var searchBox = $('.searchbox');
            var isOpen = false;
            submitIcon.click(function(){
                if(isOpen == false){
                    searchBox.addClass('searchbox-open');
                    inputBox.focus();
                    isOpen = true;
                } else {
                    searchBox.removeClass('searchbox-open');
                    inputBox.focusout();
                    isOpen = false;
                }
            });  
             submitIcon.mouseup(function(){
                    return false;
                });
            searchBox.mouseup(function(){
                    return false;
                });
            $(document).mouseup(function(){
                    if(isOpen == true){
                        $('.searchbox-icon').css('display','block');
                        submitIcon.click();
                    }
                });
        });
            function buttonUp(){
                var inputVal = $('.searchbox-input').val();
                inputVal = $.trim(inputVal).length;
                if( inputVal !== 0){
                    $('.searchbox-icon').css('display','none');
                } else {
                    $('.searchbox-input').val('');
                    $('.searchbox-icon').css('display','block');
                }
            }
```

**Menu:-**

```
$(function() {
  $('#main-menu').smartmenus({
    subMenusSubOffsetX: 1,
    subMenusSubOffsetY: -8
  });
});

// SmartMenus mobile menu toggle button
$(function() {
  var $mainMenuState = $('#main-menu-state');
  if ($mainMenuState.length) {
    // animate mobile menu
    $mainMenuState.change(function(e) {
      var $menu = $('#main-menu');
      if (this.checked) {
        $menu.hide().slideDown(250, function() { $menu.css('display', ''); });
      } else {
        $menu.show().slideUp(250, function() { $menu.css('display', ''); });
      }
    });
    // hide mobile menu beforeunload
    $(window).bind('beforeunload unload', function() {
      if ($mainMenuState[0].checked) {
        $mainMenuState[0].click();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Preloader:-

```
$(window).on('load', function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded 
            $('#status').fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation 
            $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow'); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website. 
            $('body').delay(350).css({'overflow':'visible'});
        })
```

Counter:-

```
(function($){
    $(window).on("load",function(){
        $(document).scrollzipInit();
        $(document).rollerInit();
    });
    $(window).on("load scroll resize", function(){
        $('.numscroller').scrollzip({
            showFunction    :   function() {
                                    numberRoller($(this).attr('data-slno'));
                                },
            wholeVisible    :     false,
        });
    });
    $.fn.scrollzipInit=function(){
        $('body').prepend("<div style='position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;width:0;height:0;' id='scrollzipPoint'></div>" );
    };
    $.fn.rollerInit=function(){
        var i=0;
        $('.numscroller').each(function() {
            i++;
           $(this).attr('data-slno',i); 
           $(this).addClass("roller-title-number-"+i);
        });        
    };
    $.fn.scrollzip = function(options){
        var settings = $.extend({
            showFunction    : null,
            hideFunction    : null,
            showShift       : 0,
            wholeVisible    : false,
            hideShift       : 0,
        }, options);
        return this.each(function(i,obj){
            $(this).addClass('scrollzip');
            if ( $.isFunction( settings.showFunction ) ){
                if(
                    !$(this).hasClass('isShown')&&
                    ($(window).outerHeight()+$('#scrollzipPoint').offset().top-settings.showShift)>($(this).offset().top+((settings.wholeVisible)?$(this).outerHeight():0))&&
                    ($('#scrollzipPoint').offset().top+((settings.wholeVisible)?$(this).outerHeight():0))<($(this).outerHeight()+$(this).offset().top-settings.showShift)
                ){
                    $(this).addClass('isShown');
                    settings.showFunction.call( this );
                }
            }
            if ( $.isFunction( settings.hideFunction ) ){
                if(
                    $(this).hasClass('isShown')&&
                    (($(window).outerHeight()+$('#scrollzipPoint').offset().top-settings.hideShift)<($(this).offset().top+((settings.wholeVisible)?$(this).outerHeight():0))||
                    ($('#scrollzipPoint').offset().top+((settings.wholeVisible)?$(this).outerHeight():0))>($(this).outerHeight()+$(this).offset().top-settings.hideShift))
                ){
                    $(this).removeClass('isShown');
                    settings.hideFunction.call( this );
                }
            }
            return this;
        });
    };
    function numberRoller(slno){
            var min=$('.roller-title-number-'+slno).attr('data-min');
            var max=$('.roller-title-number-'+slno).attr('data-max');
            var timediff=$('.roller-title-number-'+slno).attr('data-delay');
            var increment=$('.roller-title-number-'+slno).attr('data-increment');
            var numdiff=max-min;
            var timeout=(timediff*1000)/numdiff;
            numberRoll(slno,min,max,increment,timeout);

    }
    function numberRoll(slno,min,max,increment,timeout){//alert(slno+"="+min+"="+max+"="+increment+"="+timeout);
        if(min<=max){
            $('.roller-title-number-'+slno).html(min);
            min=parseInt(min)+parseInt(increment);
            setTimeout(function(){numberRoll(eval(slno),eval(min),eval(max),eval(increment),eval(timeout))},timeout);
        }else{
            $('.roller-title-number-'+slno).html(max);
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Did you look up how to write `.on` syntax? http://api.jquery.com/on/ Did you look up how to do strict equality in Javascript?

Comment: What kind of a question is this? It looks rather a code cleaning request, which doesn't belong at SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lucky,

Thanks for the helping hand, really appreciated.
So you meant to say that i should rewrite the code as bellow?

Updated JS:

// JavaScript Document

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        "use strict";
        var submitIcon = $('.searchbox-icon');
        var inputBox = $('.searchbox-input');
        var searchBox = $('.searchbox');
        var isOpen = false;
        submitIcon.on("click", function(){
            if(isOpen === false){
                searchBox.addClass('searchbox-open');
                inputBox.focus();
                isOpen = true;
            } else {
                searchBox.removeClass('searchbox-open');
                inputBox.focusout();
                isOpen = false;
            }
        });  
         submitIcon.on('mouseup', function(){
                return false;
            });
        searchBox.on('mouseup', function(){
                return false;
            });
        $(document).on('mouseup', function(){
                if(isOpen === true){
                    $('.searchbox-icon').css('display','block');
                    submitIcon.click();
                }
            });
    });
        function buttonUp(){
            var inputVal = $('.searchbox-input').val();
            inputVal = $.trim(inputVal).length;
            if( inputVal !== 0){
                $('.searchbox-icon').css('display','none');
            } else {
                $('.searchbox-input').val('');
                $('.searchbox-icon').css('display','block');
            }
        }
```

1) Just replace all your `submitIcon.click(function(){` with `submitIcon.on("click", function(){` (and all other events).

2) Strict comparison is `===`, in your code I can see for example `if(isOpen == false){` - you should replace it with `if(isOpen === false){`; you can see well-defined difference between strict and non-strict equality comparison in this answer [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: hey I just reviewed your edit - you missed `mouseup` events - should also rewrite them on `on` - I did it for you